# Where should I create a projection of a data in MVP? Is Presenter O.K.?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, design-patterns, mvp

Can you advise if it is a violation of MVP pattern if the presenter has a method that 'summarizes' a big datatable recieved from a service in order to produce a projection to be passed into the View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where else would you do it? Model is data source. View is for displaying data. Presenter is where you manipulate data.

I don't find anything wrong with the projection being done in presenter. Thats where it should be done.

Comment: My concern was if Presenter should only implement a kind of orchestrating logic other than modifying the data which results a new version of data? (To me it sounded more than presenting a data) Am I stressing myself unneceserly?

Comment: Remember that a presenter is really a ViewPresenter, so it makes perfect sense to make construct ViewModels in them when necessary.